# Git: Commands to read index

Tags: git

Is there any builtin commands to read a Git index?

Since the index is a flat file, I expect the result to be something like:

```
<mode> <pathname> <object SHA-1>
<mode> <pathname> <object SHA-1>
<mode> <pathname> <object SHA-1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with

```
git ls-files --stage
```

There are a number of other options to [`git ls-files`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html) that produce different kinds of output.